# Programmatically display user names according to the user profile type

Tags: 7, users

This is a Drupal 7 site. I have a profile2 module installed with several profile types for different users. The user name should be displayed according to the profile type:

- For personal users - the user name should be build from the first and last name fields.
- For business users, the user name should be taken from the business name field.

How do I display user names programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I've put the following code on a module:

```
<?
// Find the type of the current user
function mymodule_get_usertype(&$user) {
  $usertype = 'other';
  if (is_array($user->roles) && 
      in_array('authenticated user', array_values($user->roles))) {
    $usertype = 'individual';
  }
  elseif (is_array($user->roles) && 
          in_array('non authenticated user', array_values($user->roles))) {
    $usertype = 'individual';
  }
  elseif (is_array($user->roles) && 
          in_array('business', array_values($user->roles))) {
    $usertype = 'business';
  }
  return $usertype;
}

// Implements hook_username_alter,
// to display the user name according to the profile type
function mymodule_username_alter(&$name, $account) {

  $profile_type = mymodule_get_usertype($account);
  if (!empty($profile_type)) :
    $profiledata = profile2_by_uid_load($account->uid, $profile_type);
  endif;

  if ($profiledata) :

    switch ($profile_type) {
      case 'individual':
        $firstname = field_get_items('profile2', $profiledata, 'field_first_name');
        $firstname = $firstname[0]['safe_value'];
        $lastname = field_get_items('profile2', $profiledata, 'field_last_name');
        $lastname = $lastname[0]['safe_value'];
        $name = "$firstname $lastname" ;
        break;

      case 'business':
        $bizname = field_get_items('profile2', $profiledata, 'field_biz_name');
        $bizname = $bizname[0]['safe_value'];
        $name = $bizname;
        break;

      default:
        // For admin users, no change
    }
  endif;
}
?>
```

The result is that the new name is displayed whenever a user name is displayed (e.g. on the menus, on the user page, or on the user listing pages)

Comment: The method chosen is correct but I would recommend checking the for empty results from field_get_items() instead of assuming there is always going to be a value. The $user parameter doesn't need to be a reference in mymodule_get_usertype(). I would use elseif for the role checking to reduce unnecessary code running. - It is also good to keep with the drupal coding standards when providing help to try to promote good practice. https://drupal.org/coding-standards

Comment: Thanks for the code review. Question is if I can directly get the values without using the "$firstname[0]['safe_value'];" syntax.

Comment: Nope there is no way around that.